# Matplotlib and cartopy contours coming out completely wrong

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, gis, cartopy

I'm trying to plot latency maps of the world (for the moment, from London).

I have a database with a series of latencies between GPS points.  I'd like to plot these on a map of the world with contour lines at various levels of latency, eg 50ms, 100ms, 200ms+ etc.

Right now I'm working with [some sample code from the cartopy project](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/contour_labels.html) for drawing labelled contours.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from collections import defaultdict

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from cartopy.examples.waves import sample_data


def main():
    # lat, long and then latency from london
    zs = [
        (55.30927, 25.07725, 123.822),
        (19.81889, 41.3275, 61.154),
        (-58.37723, -34.61315, 250.024),
        (16.37208, 48.20849, 26.987),
        (15.45, 47.06667, 49.47),
        (115.8614, -31.95224, 273.459),
        (138.59863, -34.92866, 257.056),
        (151.20732, -33.86785, 258.382),
        (144.96332, -37.814, 259.542),
        (149.12807, -35.28346, 291.766),
        (153.02809, -27.46794, 283.675),
        (49.89201, 40.37767, 89.569),
        (90.40744, 23.7104, 232.381),
        (5.56749, 50.63373, 11.093),
        (4.34878, 50.85045, 9.644),
        (3.22424, 51.20892, 10.713),
        (4.40026, 51.22047, 10.905),
        (27.91667, 43.21667, 47.367),
        (23.32415, 42.69751, 52.414),
        (-34.86306, -7.115, 208.491),
        (-46.63611, -23.5475, 180.227),
        (-47.92972, -15.77972, 227.893),
        (-113.46871, 53.55014, 138.725),
        (-73.58781, 45.50884, 84.456),
        (-75.69812, 45.41117, 83.592),
        (-106.66892, 52.13238, 108.197),
        (-79.4163, 43.70011, 90.885),
        (-123.11934, 49.24966, 130.308),
        (-97.14704, 49.8844, 159.187),
        (-63.57291, 44.6464, 74.226),
        (-71.21454, 46.81228, 85.994),
        (8.55, 47.36667, 22.503),
        (8.96004, 46.01008, 33.557),
        (6.63282, 46.516, 27.375),
        (7.44744, 46.94809, 18.838),
        (7.57327, 47.55839, 27.376),
        (-70.64827, -33.45694, 195.647),
        (114.0683, 22.54554, 233.257),
        (121.45806, 31.22222, 191.371),
        (120.16142, 30.29365, 237.881),
        (114.87944, 40.81, 206.936),
        (-75.56359, 6.25184, 150.812),
        (-74.08175, 4.60971, 153.555),
        (-84.11651, 10.00236, 140.832),
        (33.03794, 34.68406, 64.037),
        (14.42076, 50.08804, 27.247),
        (16.60796, 49.19522, 29.384),
        (11.07752, 49.45421, 17.739),
        (11.57549, 48.13743, 20.171),
        (9.99302, 53.55073, 43.907),
        (8.68417, 50.11552, 13.733),
        (6.77616, 51.22172, 12.371),
        (12.10466, 47.7044, 19.85),
        (12.56553, 55.67594, 16.867),
        (3.08746, 36.73225, 40.629),
        (-78.52495, -0.22985, 161.671),
        (24.75353, 59.43696, 34.33),
        (31.24967, 30.06263, 63.373),
        (-0.37739, 39.46975, 32.652),
        (-3.70256, 40.4165, 23.838),
        (2.15899, 41.38879, 29.685),
        (24.93545, 60.16952, 33.84),
        (7.74553, 48.58392, 13.785),
        (3.17456, 50.69421, 4.4),
        (2.3488, 48.85341, 8.154),
        (4.84671, 45.74846, 21.794),
        (-1.61396, 54.97328, 5.601),
        (-2.23743, 53.48095, 7.15),
        (0.51667, 51.26667, 1.404),
        (-1.12902, 50.79509, 3.552),
        (-3.19648, 55.95206, 10.398),
        (-1.51217, 52.40656, 6.462),
        (-2.07972, 51.90006, 4.167),
        (-3.18, 51.48, 6.116),
        (-2.59665, 51.45523, 4.497),
        (-5.92541, 54.59682, 10.33),
        (44.83368, 41.69411, 88.784),
        (-0.1969, 5.55602, 97.088),
        (23.72784, 37.98376, 56.074),
        (22.93086, 40.64361, 61.766),
        (-90.51327, 14.64072, 342.363),
        (114.17469, 22.27832, 219.061),
        (15.97798, 45.81444, 31.988),
        (19.04045, 47.49835, 28.312),
        (106.84513, -6.21462, 191.802),
        (-6.24889, 53.33306, 11.926),
        (-6.92611, 52.84083, 12.585),
        (35.21633, 31.76904, 63.795),
        (34.78057, 32.08088, 111.049),
        (-4.48333, 54.15, 14.732),
        (78.15538, 11.65376, 70.362),
        (73.85535, 18.51957, 274.087),
        (77.22445, 28.63576, 150.969),
        (80.27847, 13.08784, 144.037),
        (75.8333, 22.71792, 137.159),
        (78.45636, 17.38405, 187.213),
        (72.88261, 19.07283, 187.64),
        (77.59369, 12.97194, 131.413),
        (-21.89541, 64.13548, 38.428),
        (13.33561, 38.13205, 52.313),
        (12.33265, 45.43713, 38.471),
        (12.51133, 41.89193, 31.075),
        (9.18951, 45.46427, 30.8),
        (13.34109, 41.63976, 41.74),
        (11.88068, 43.46276, 34.63),
        (139.69171, 35.6895, 215.214),
        (135.50218, 34.69374, 233.671),
        (141.35, 43.06667, 242.554),
        (36.81667, -1.28333, 174.557),
        (104.91601, 11.56245, 208.175),
        (126.9784, 37.566, 266.233),
        (73.10211, 49.80187, 123.06),
        (35.50157, 33.89332, 64.207),
        (25.2798, 54.68916, 38.825),
        (23.31667, 55.93333, 42.406),
        (6.13, 49.61167, 15.731),
        (24.10589, 56.946, 38.292),
        (-5.00028, 34.03313, 77.605),
        (28.8575, 47.00556, 51.354),
        (14.5148, 35.89968, 48.426),
        (-103.39182, 20.66682, 132.319),
        (3.39467, 6.45407, 96.877),
        (4.29861, 52.07667, 8.78),
        (4.47917, 51.9225, 6.952),
        (6.56667, 53.21917, 8.917),
        (5.47778, 51.44083, 8.77),
        (5.71806, 52.525, 7.052),
        (4.88969, 52.37403, 6.88),
        (4.66111, 51.86583, 9.274),
        (10.74609, 59.91273, 28.073),
        (5.32415, 60.39299, 28.998),
        (174.77557, -41.28664, 282.141),
        (172.63333, -43.53333, 273.846),
        (174.76349, -36.84853, 279.023),
        (-79.51973, 8.9936, 150.216),
        (-77.02824, -12.04318, 163.241),
        (120.9822, 14.6042, 220.693),
        (120.33325, 16.04313, 245.787),
        (74.35071, 31.558, 150.221),
        (21.01178, 52.22977, 31.504),
        (18.64912, 54.35227, 38.029),
        (-66.10572, 18.46633, 106.983),
        (-9.13333, 38.71667, 50.867),
        (26.10626, 44.43225, 47.648),
        (21.90333, 43.32472, 48.541),
        (20.46513, 44.80401, 38.377),
        (30.31413, 59.93863, 36.871),
        (37.61556, 55.75222, 49.041),
        (49.12214, 55.78874, 58.591),
        (82.9346, 55.0415, 127.4),
        (131.87353, 43.10562, 147.576),
        (46.72185, 24.68773, 88.155),
        (18.06871, 59.32938, 26.838),
        (11.96679, 57.70716, 56.335),
        (103.85007, 1.28967, 251.641),
        (14.50513, 46.05108, 36.656),
        (17.10674, 48.14816, 27.031),
        (-55.16682, 5.86638, 166.626),
        (100.50144, 13.75398, 265.619),
        (10.16579, 36.81897, 52.035),
        (27.13838, 38.41273, 67.678),
        (32.85427, 39.91987, 60.337),
        (28.94966, 41.01384, 51.519),
        (29.06013, 40.19559, 72.622),
        (121.53185, 25.04776, 261.82),
        (39.26951, -6.82349, 150.264),
        (30.5238, 50.45466, 41.29),
        (36.25272, 49.98081, 58.363),
        (32.58219, 0.31628, 159.655),
        (-77.03637, 38.89511, 78.045),
        (-81.65565, 30.33218, 94.374),
        (-80.19366, 25.77427, 99.16),
        (-81.37924, 28.53834, 97.119),
        (-82.45843, 27.94752, 101.628),
        (-84.38798, 33.749, 87.471),
        (-81.09983, 32.08354, 119.433),
        (-86.15804, 39.76838, 91.394),
        (-90.07507, 29.95465, 116.938),
        (-76.61219, 39.29038, 77.512),
        (-94.57857, 39.09973, 98.802),
        (-90.19789, 38.62727, 90.391),
        (-90.18481, 32.29876, 105.299),
        (-82.55402, 35.60095, 87.855),
        (-80.84313, 35.22709, 92.297),
        (-78.63861, 35.7721, 83.355),
        (-84.51439, 39.12711, 96.657),
        (-82.99879, 39.96118, 85.065),
        (-97.51643, 35.46756, 108.011),
        (-75.16379, 39.95233, 70.659),
        (-83.92074, 35.96064, 111.042),
        (-90.04898, 35.14953, 106.578),
        (-97.74306, 30.26715, 117.634),
        (-96.80667, 32.78306, 113.133),
        (-95.36327, 29.76328, 105.161),
        (-98.49363, 29.42412, 117.229),
        (-93.60911, 41.60054, 101.56),
        (-87.65005, 41.85003, 89.144),
        (-88.30535, 41.88753, 26.006),
        (-86.25001, 41.68338, 89.071),
        (-71.05977, 42.35843, 75.733),
        (-83.04575, 42.33143, 92.257),
        (-84.55553, 42.73253, 97.811),
        (-93.26384, 44.97997, 97.597),
        (-96.66696, 40.8, 97.95),
        (-74.39904, 40.49927, 69.437),
        (-74.05653, 40.78955, 71.265),
        (-73.75623, 42.65258, 74.285),
        (-78.87837, 42.88645, 79.13),
        (-73.96625, 40.78343, 68.356),
        (-74.00597, 40.71427, 71.41),
        (-76.14742, 43.04812, 76.038),
        (-81.8418, 41.23811, 83.061),
        (-81.69541, 41.4995, 93.716),
        (-83.55521, 41.66394, 97.349),
        (-79.99589, 40.44062, 87.723),
        (-75.6649, 41.40916, 73.833),
        (-88.01983, 44.51916, 102.133),
        (-112.07404, 33.44838, 130.966),
        (-121.98857, 37.54827, 134.523),
        (-118.24368, 34.05223, 136.396),
        (-121.4944, 38.58157, 136.928),
        (-117.16472, 32.71571, 146.006),
        (-122.41942, 37.77493, 141.373),
        (-121.89496, 37.33939, 133.461),
        (-104.82136, 38.83388, 108.739),
        (-104.9847, 39.73915, 121.039),
        (-106.65114, 35.08449, 164.648),
        (-115.13722, 36.17497, 146.236),
        (-122.39168, 40.58654, 156.6),
        (-122.67621, 45.52345, 130.65),
        (-123.34174, 43.2165, 147.008),
        (-111.89105, 40.76078, 151.18),
        (-122.33207, 47.60621, 129.576),
        (-157.85833, 21.30694, 186.991),
        (-56.18816, -34.90328, 228.291),
        (-66.87919, 10.48801, 148.292),
        (106.62965, 10.82302, 305.353),
        (105.84117, 21.0245, 240.46),
        (21.16688, 42.67272, 48.995),
        (28.04363, -26.20227, 165.392),
        (18.42322, -33.92584, 143.62),
    ]

    z = np.array(zs, dtype="float")
    breakpoint()

    fig = plt.figure()

    # Setup a global EckertIII map with faint coastlines.
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.EckertIII())
    ax.set_global()
    ax.coastlines("110m", alpha=0.1)

    # Add colourful filled contours.
    filled_c = ax.contourf(z, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    # And black line contours.
    line_c = ax.contour(
        z, levels=filled_c.levels, colors=["black"], transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()
    )

    # Uncomment to make the line contours invisible.
    # plt.setp(line_c.collections, visible=False)

    # Add a colorbar for the filled contour.
    fig.colorbar(filled_c, orientation="horizontal")

    # Use the line contours to place contour labels.
    ax.clabel(
        line_c,  # Typically best results when labelling line contours.
        colors=["black"],
        manual=False,  # Automatic placement vs manual placement.
        inline=True,  # Cut the line where the label will be placed.
        fmt=" {:.0f} ".format,  # Labes as integers, with some extra space.
    )

    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Instead of getting nice contours, I get this image:

[image: bad map of contours]

What's my problem?

Am I passing the wrong args to the matplotlib functions?

Is numpy somehow interpreting my floats wrong?

Comment: You need to grid your data or use something like tricontour though I don’t know if that works for cartopy)

Comment: What does "grid your data" mean?

Comment: “Grid your data” means to put it on a grid.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know what you mean by that.  Do you mean converting it into a table (I feel like that's not far from what I have..) or somehow using interpolation to get smoother values out of it - which is more or less appropriate for my data

Comment: If you plot your x and y data they are just scatter shot across the map.  You can use tricontour to contour data like that, or you can put onto a regular lat/lon grid using something like https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate data into `lat`, `long`, and `height`. Then use `tricontour` type functions to generate the plot. Here is the relevant part of the modified code that handles the data and generate the plot.

```
# more code before this (see the question)
zs = np.array(zs)
# get `lat`, `long`, and `height` separately
lats, lons, zzz = zs[:,0], zs[:,1], zs[:,2]

fig = plt.figure()

# Setup a global EckertIII map with faint coastlines.
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.EckertIII())
ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines("110m", alpha=0.1)

# Add colourful filled contours.
filled_c = ax.tricontourf(lats, lons, zzz, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# And black line contours.
line_c = ax.tricontour(
    lats, lons, zzz, levels=filled_c.levels, colors=["black"], transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()
)

# Uncomment to make the line contours invisible.
# plt.setp(line_c.collections, visible=False)

# Add a colorbar for the filled contour.
fig.colorbar(filled_c, orientation="horizontal")

# Use the line contours to place contour labels.
ax.clabel(
    line_c,  # Typically best results when labelling line contours.
    colors=["black"],
    manual=False,  # Automatic placement vs manual placement.
    inline=True,  # Cut the line where the label will be placed.
    fmt=" {:.0f} ".format,  # Labes as integers, with some extra space.
)

plt.show()
```

[image: contourplot]